# How to use AND *and* OR in a Drupal taxonomy URL

Tags: url, drupal-6, boolean-logic, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I'm new to Drupal but thanks to our old friend O'Reilly I'm blazing through my own taxonomy-based, navigational search-paradigmed menu in Drupal 6. Using only Core modules at the moment (I don't want to *unnecessarily* complicate things), I am building a Primary nav menu which pulls several taxonomy terms together.

Now I know that I can implement AND by using the URL `/taxonomy/term/1,2` and I can implement OR by using the URL `/taxonomy/term/1+2`. What I need to do is essentially an AND *plus* an OR, and I've tried the following URLs, neither of which works:

- `/taxonomy/term/1,7+8`
- `/taxonomy/term/1/7+8`

What I'd *like* to say here is "show me all nodes tagged with term 1, AND also show me all nodes tagged with EITHER terms 7 OR 8. I've tried searching Drupal and Google and even StackOverflow, but as you can imagine search terms like AND and OR really suck for results.

All comments, especially those concerning best practice, gratefully received. I would prefer not to have to resort to a module at this stage; I'm trying to get as far as I can through the site before I begin chucking modules at a wall. ;)

Comment: Hmm. Found this: http://drupal.org/node/895224 which states it's not possible to combine AND and OR across vocabularies, but my requirement is to combine AND and OR within the same vocabulary. I'll keep looking, I guess.

Comment: Since we've begun using the module Views for this project, I guess this question is redundant, as I can use Views to build queries which fulfil these requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the Drupal 6 module Views 2 to fulfil these requirements, so this question can be closed.